# flutter Firestore transaction does this work?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update value with `Transaction` firstly I tried like this but app will crash at `tx.get`.
I think it's plugins issue I saw a couple of issues in git.

```
 await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((tx) async {
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('votes').document('6z2C2cSwnHNXaRNmzs4P');
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await tx.get(ref); // crash here
    if (snap.exists) {
      await tx.update(snap.reference, {'vote': snap.data['vote'] + 1});
    } 
  });
```

I just changed `tx.get` to `ref.get` and it works in terms of updating value.
Then what I would like to ask is if I change like this, would this still work atomically?

```
 await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((tx) async {
    DocumentReference ref = Firestore.instance.collection('votes').document('6z2C2cSwnHNXaRNmzs4P');
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await ref.get(); // changed here
    if (snap.exists) {
      await tx.update(snap.reference, {'vote': snap.data['vote'] + 1});
    }
  });
```

Comment: any updates on that? Is it the right way to do transaction?

Comment: Sorry I'm still not sure.